# How to select a file from the list?

Tags: c#

I'm learning programming for one month and as part of my learning I'm writing a program in which you can edit .txt files, it was going reasonably well until I add the files to a list, display them along with their indexes (so that you can then choose which file you want to edit), but I'm completely at a loss as to what to do now. Let's say there will be 10 files in a folder, how do I make it so I don't have to write 10 case's in switch?

Code of method:

```
public void ShowTxt()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    var txt = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(Path.GetFileName);

    List<string> files = new List<string> {};

    foreach (string file in txt)
    {
        files.Add(file);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{files.IndexOf(file)}]  {file}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the result you are expecting ? and what is txt ?

Comment: I want the program to show me all the .txt files that are in the folder and that I can choose which one I want to edit. The code I showed shows the file names and their indexes in a list, but I don't know how to make it so I can select any of them for later editing.

Comment: You can print an index per entry in the list, then let the user select the index and with it you can determine the filename from the list.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you tell us what is the type of your txt variable ? And do you want to select a file in your console ?

Comment: @LYass [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0) returns a string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```cs
public void ShowTxt()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    var files = Directory
        .GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        .ToList();

    for (var index = 0; index < files.Count; index++)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(files[index]);
        Console.WriteLine($"[{index}] {filename}");
    }
}
```

Then you can read from the standard input a file index and use it to get one from `files`. It will be the full file path which you can use to manipulate the file.

Answer (score 0):

to change the name of a file you need 3 things : the list of files, the index of the file you want to change and finally the new name for the file.
If you put all of this you have for exemple :

```cs
files[i] = "newname.txt";
```

i is the index.

So you can put that in a function to make it easy